# Java: Passing a reference to a variable as an argument for a method

Tags: java, methods, reference, arguments, argument-passing

When passing an object as an argument for a method, all changes that happen to the argument inside the method, affect the "original" object as well. That's because the argument is a reference to the object.

But I also want to do the same with variables- I want all changes that happen inside the method to affect the "original" variable. But I don't know how. I want to do this, because some times more than one local variables need to be processed in the same way.

How can I pass a reference to a variable as an argument for a method?

Comment: Local variables in a method work in the same way. It would be better to show a sample of what you're trying to do. Also, Java never passes by reference, only by value.

Comment: @Keyser that's not a good advice =\.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Kind of true :p But it works. Passing objects isn't always the right choice.

Comment: @Keyser the fact that works doesn't mean it would be the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no other choice than to store the variable inside an object, and to pass the object. All arguments are passed by value in Java.

The object can be `this` (i.e. the variable is in fact a field of the current object).

Comment: Then a guess it is a good idea to simply do this: `variable = processVariable(variable);`?

Comment: You can of course do that. But it will only work for one variable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean by the word "variable"?  Do you mean a local reference inside the method, a primitive that's passed in, or something else?

Java references and primitives are passed by value.  You cannot alter them, no matter how much you may want to.

Comment: By a variable I mean a primitive- integer, double, e.t.c.

Comment: Can't be altered with Java.  You'll need another language.